# Запись потокового Аудио в Android

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Есть приложение, которое воспроизводит потоковое аудио из интернета, используя MediaPlayer. Возможно ли как-то через MediaRecorder записать воспроизводимое аудио в формате mp3? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381969/android-how-to-record-mp3-radio-audio-stream

Comment: Спасибо. попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Из ссылки в комментариях:</sub>

Попробуй сохранить аудиопоток побайтово и сохранить в отдельный файл. Пример:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myradio,com/stream.mp3");
inputStream = url.openStream();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "url.openStream()");

fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FileOutputStream: " + outputSource);

int c;

while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bytesRead=" + bytesRead);
    fileOutputStream.write(c);
    bytesRead++;
}
```

[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384161/2907755).